# Sorting a query after comparing two collections

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mongodb-query

I'm trying to compare two collections and return data sorted in the order original order sent, using javascript, node.js

Config:

**Collection A:**

```
"community": [ 
{ "_id": "62203a179aef2e193cdde104", "sort": 3, "rId": "621842a5e6c0f8002768cd11" }, 
{ "_id": "62203a179aef2e193cdde105", "sort": 1, "rId": "62184291e6c0f8002768cd10" }, 
{ "_id": "62203a179aef2e193cdde106", "sort": 2, "rId": "6218427ae6c0f8002768cd12" } 
]
```

**Collection B:**

```
{ "_id": "6218427ae6c0f8002768cd0f", "captionText": "Test 1" }, 
{ "_id": "62184291e6c0f8002768cd10", "captionText": "Test 2" }, 
{ "_id": "621842a5e6c0f8002768cd11", "captionText": "Test 3" }
```

My Code:

```
let output = []

let findId = community.map(temp => {return temp.rId})
                let findX = await CollectionB.find({'_id': {$in: findId}}, '_id captionText')
                output.push(...findX)
console.log(output)
```

This code returns the output in the order `[{"Test 1"}, {"Test 2"}, {"Test 3"}]`

However I want to return the order based on the `sort` value in Collection A.

I want this output `[{"sort": 1}, {"sort": 2}, {"sort": 3}]`, along with the data populated from Collection B.

Any help and explanations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In `Collection B`, is `"_id": "6218427ae6c0f8002768cd0f"` correct?

Comment: Correct, the `"_id"` from `Collection B` is used as reference to `"rId"` from `Collection A`.

Comment: I just happened to notice that there is no reference to `"6218427ae6c0f8002768cd0f"`.